# Comparison between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an auditing script that takes a sample from an excel file. The code work just fine, but I'm trying to make a comparison between two dataframes, the initial one and the sampled one, and mark items as "Audit" in the original frame. I've used both codes below to no success:

```
df['Retailer Item ID'] in final['Retailer Item ID'], df['Track Item'] = 
'Audit'

if df.loc[df['Retailer Item ID'] == final['Retailer Item ID']:
    df['Track Item'] = 'Audit']
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In python you have to use one "equals to"  mark instead of two. One assigns a value the other one checks if it is equal to the other variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['Track Item']=np.where(df['Retailer Item ID'] == final['Retailer Item ID'], 'Audit','null')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a merge and pass the indicator as a parameter:

```
df_merged=pd.merge(df,final,left_on='Track Item', right_on='Retailer Item ID', how='left',indicator=True)
```

You will see a "True" value in the indicator column for each item that you want to include in your audit sample.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: df.loc[df['Retailer Item ID'].isin(final['Retailer Item ID']), 'Track Item'] = 'Audit'